# Chrome Extension - Prevent Page Reload

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that loads popup.html when icon is clicked. I have an iFrame inside that page. However, each time someone opens the popup, the page (along with iFrame) refreshes. Is there any way to prevent the page to be re-loaded every time someone opens the popup? (Is there a way to cache it?)

Comment: hey i'm facing the issue. did you find a fix?

Comment: in the iframe handler did you tried "window.stop" OR chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"window.stop()"});